# Android Widget implementation

Tags: java, android, android-widget

Hi I apologise in advance if this question is daft.  I am fairly new to Android programming and I learn fast.

Any ways I have just created a Task Reminder application and I would like to turn/implement that application into a widget that you can view on the home screen?

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about what your app does all I can really do is point you to the [documentation on widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) which would be a good place to start anyway.  One thing I can tell you though is to make sure that your application is a good fit for a widget.  Widgets were purposefully designed to be very limited in Android.  There are only a handful of views that can be used and you can't update them very frequently without it being a major headache.  You may just want to make a part of your app into a widget.  Widgets aren't just apps on the launcher.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's probably possible.  Take a look at http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/04/simple-complete-app-widget-part-1.html for a decent example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you like to create an "App Widget". A manual about doing so is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).